# How to select a specific month and year?

Tags: mysql

I want to select november 2015 and november 2016. Is there any function or something?

I can get october 2016 by using this:

```
WHERE YEAR(A_Date)= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
MONTH(A_Date)= MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Is there any similar way to get november 2016 and november 2015?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM A_Date)='November' 
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A_Date) IN ('2015', '2016')
```

OR

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(A_Date,'%Y-%m') = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE())-1,'-11') 
AND DATE_FORMAT(A_Date,'%Y-%m') = CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-11')
```